# Text inside AnimatedContainer overflows

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using an AnimatedContainer and LinearProgressIndicator inside an AnimatedContainer. This is my current code:

```
LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) => AnimatedContainer(
                    width: expanded ? constraints.maxWidth : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(trackName, maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          Text(artists.join(", "), maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          if (currentProgressValue != null)
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(currentProgress.minutes.toString() + ":" + currentProgress.seconds.toString(),
                                    maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                    valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(MyTheme.primaryColor),
                                    value: currentProgressValue / songDuration,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

The problem is that the first text inside the Row after "if (currentProgressValue != null)" is overflowing when the AnimatedContainer is compressing. The solution that worked was to put both Text and LinearProgressIndicator inside Expanded but doing that the split the space in half and it is not what I want. I wont LinearProgressIndicator to fill the remaining space of Text. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

İnstead of expanded use flexible. wrap widgets that might overflow while container gets bigger with Flexible.

Comment: I've tried that but the 2 widgets are still sharing the width resulting in both of them of equal size.

Comment: Okay, as I understand you do not want them to take equal space. (correct me if I am wrong) Did you try flex parameter of the expanded widget? it specifies how should widgets inside flex widget should take (for example you have 2 widgets in row and you have flex for them 2 and 1 row will be splitted to three and flex with 2 will take 2 times more place)

Comment: Yes, Now I've solved with flex but I would have preferred a way to let one of the 2 widgets get all the remaining space instead of splitting it by flex percentage.

Comment: You can wrap Text widget with container and give it a width and expanded widget will take remaining space

Comment: If I do this the Text will overflow when I set the AnimatedContainer width = 0

Answer (score 0):

wrap you overflows widget in flexible widget.

> For example

```
class MenuItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuItemWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.selected,
    required this.onPress,
    required this.idx,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final int selected;
  final int idx;
  final void Function(int idx) onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onPress(idx);
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(SizeConst.smallInsect),
        width: selected == idx ? 90 : 40,
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: selected == idx ? Colors.white : null,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
              color: selected == idx ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
            ),
            if (selected == idx)
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                  child: Text(
                    'Home',
                    style: theme.textTheme.titleMedium,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Here Text field getting overflow. so I wrapped with Flexible Widget.
> Now It is working fine.